# How do I get terminal in OSX recognise Regex as filenames?

Tags: regex, bash, macos, terminal, glob

In OS X terminal I have the following:

`for filename in ^.* 2\.jpeg$; do printf "$filename\n"; done;`

which I want to match filenames in the current folder ending in the string " 2.jpeg"

but it's not being recognised as Regex and it's not searching the current directory.  It simply prints the two strings:

`^.*
2\.jpeg$`

obviously there's more I want to do with these files but I can't get it to match.  Putting the regex in inverted commas doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: If you need to use regex, you could always use `ls | grep ^.* 2\.jpeg$`

Comment: @StevenDoggart: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: @StevenDoggart thanks, that looks useful in my case.

Comment: @Cyrus parsing ls looks the easiest and best option for a noob like me.  So thanks for those issues, I'll watch out for them.

Comment: @StevenDoggart If I want to use capture groups and backreferences later then regex is the only way I know of.

Comment: @oguzismail in case it helps clear up any misunderstanding your answer doesn't answer the question because I needed to capture strings (partial filename) and backreference them, which I understand your glob patterns wouldn't support easily. So I got the job done by parsing ls in the end. But I did upvote your helpful answer and comments so you got some rep for your efforts from me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a glob pattern, regex doesn't work in `for ... in ...` construct. And don't print variables like that, use `echo` or `printf '%s\n' "$variable"`.

```
for filename in ./*' '2.jpeg; do
    echo "$filename"
done
```

Comment: I suggest to use`*" "2.jpeg`.

Comment: Also, if a filename starts with a dash, the command being run on it might misinterpret the filename as an option; using `./*` instead of `*` in the glob prevents that.

Comment: Did I not use a wildcard?

Comment: @oguzismail a wildcard is a component that can be used within a regex. I used a wildcard within a regex.

Comment: @user334732 okay, edited my answer with correct term

Comment: "Wild card" isn't really a term used in describing regular expressions, although `.` basically fits the definition. Patterns have two different wildcards, `?` which matches a single character, and `*` which matches 0 or more. (`*` and `?` in regular expressions are operators that act on *other* regular expressions.)

Comment: Am I right in thinking glob patterns won't permit capturing groups and backreferences? The motivation for this is to create a directory named after each filename.

Comment: @user334732 Yes you're right. That doesn't sound difficult

Comment: @oguzismail so easy even I might be able to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
for filename in *2.jpeg; do echo ${filename}; done
```

This gives the following for me:

```
for filename in *2.jpeg; do echo ${filename}; done
2.jpeg
a2.jpeg
```

In a directory with 3 files:

```
touch 1.jpeg
touch a2.jpeg
touch 2.jpeg
```